# Using CURAND inside a Thrust functor

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Is it possible to use CURAND together with Thrust inside a device functor? A minimum code example can be:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct Move
{
    Move() {}

    using Position = thrust::tuple<double, double>;

    __host__ __device__
    Position operator()(Position p)
    {
        thrust::get<0>(p) += 1.0; // use CURAND to add a random N(0,1)
        thrust::get<1>(p) += 1.0; // use CURAND to add a random N(0,1)
        return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Create vectors on device
    thrust::device_vector<double> p1(10, 0.0);
    thrust::device_vector<double> p2(10, 0.0);

    // Create zip iterators
    auto pBeg = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(p1.begin(), p2.begin()));
    auto pEnd = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(p1.end(),   p2.end()  ));

    // Move points in the vectors
    thrust::transform(pBeg, pEnd, pBeg, Move());

    // Print result (just for debug)
    thrust::copy(p1.begin(), p1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
    thrust::copy(p2.begin(), p2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

What is the right way to create random numbers inside the operator function?

Comment: you have to use the cuRAND device API which is documented here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#device-api-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use CURAND together with Thrust inside a device functor?

Yes, it's possible.  As indicated by @m.s. most of what you need from curand can be gotten from the [curand device api example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#device-api-example)  in the curand documentation.  (In fact, there is even a full thrust/curand sample code in the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#thrust-and-curand-example))

We can mimic the behavior of the setup kernel indicated there with a thrust algorithm call, eg. `thrust::for_each_n` to setup the initial curand state variables for each device vector element.

After that, it is only necessary to pass the initialized curand state to your `Move` functor via an additional iterator in your zip iterators, and then call `curand_uniform` (for example) within the functor.

Here is a fully worked example, based on your code:

```
$ cat t20.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>

const int seed = 1234;
const int ds = 10;
const int offset = 0;

struct Move
{
    Move() {}

    using Position = thrust::tuple<double, double, curandState>;

    __device__
    Position operator()(Position p)
    {
        curandState s = thrust::get<2>(p);
        thrust::get<0>(p) += curand_uniform(&s); // use CURAND to add a random N(0,1)
        thrust::get<1>(p) += curand_uniform(&s); // use CURAND to add a random N(0,1)
        thrust::get<2>(p) = s;
        return p;
    }
};

struct curand_setup
{
    using init_tuple = thrust::tuple<int, curandState &>;
    __device__
    void operator()(init_tuple t){
      curandState s;
      int id = thrust::get<0>(t);
      curand_init(seed, id, offset, &s);
      thrust::get<1>(t) = s;
      }
};

int main()
{
    // Create vectors on device
    thrust::device_vector<double> p1(ds, 0.0);
    thrust::device_vector<double> p2(ds, 0.0);
    thrust::device_vector<curandState> s1(ds);

    // Create zip iterators
    auto pBeg = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(p1.begin(), p2.begin(), s1.begin()));
    auto pEnd = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(p1.end(),   p2.end(), s1.end()  ));
    auto pInit = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), s1.begin()));
    // initialize random generator
    thrust::for_each_n(pInit, ds, curand_setup());
    // Move points in the vectors
    thrust::transform(pBeg, pEnd, pBeg, Move());

    // Print result (just for debug)
    thrust::copy(p1.begin(), p1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
    thrust::copy(p2.begin(), p2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -std=c++11 t20.cu -o t20 -lcurand
$ ./t20
0.145468
0.820181
0.550399
0.29483
0.914733
0.868979
0.321921
0.782857
0.0113023
0.28545
0.434899
0.926417
0.811845
0.308556
0.557235
0.501246
0.206681
0.123377
0.539587
0.198575
$
```

Regarding this question:

> What is the right way to create random numbers inside the operator function?

There is no problem with using curand in thrust, but you might also want to be aware that thrust has a built in [RNG facility](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__random.html) and there is a fully worked usage example [here](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/monte_carlo.cu).

Comment: This works perfectly. I prefer CURAND because it ensures a good quality of the random numbers using sequences instead of different seeds. However, I tried using `ds = 1000000` and the program crashes. It should not be a memory problem (each curandState is 48b).

Comment: It doesn't crash for me with ds=1000000.  What OS, GPU, CUDA version, and GPU arch are you compiling for?  If you are on windows visual studio, be sure you are building a 64-bit (x64) release project, not a win32 project and not a debug project.  By the way, the CURAND docs themselves have a [thrust + CURAND example code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/device-api-overview.html#thrust-and-curand-example)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, GeForce GTX 745/PCIe/SSE2, CUDA 8.0, arch=sm_50, the error I have is: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'  what():  the launch timed out and was terminated`

Comment: Thank you for the link, although I think it is better to use the `thread_id` as a sequence id instead of seed (like you did in this solution).

Comment: Your kernel is running too long on a GPU that is hosting a display.  Read [this](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x). It's not as a result of any defect in the code.